# What is the official term to use to call the one who posted a question?

Tags: discussion, terminology

This maybe sound very "common sense" but is there a official term here in stackoverflow to call the one who posted a question?

I searched some posts and I saw "asker", "poster", "one who posted a question".

So is there a term for it?

When I try to "ask a question" here in Meta I don't know what term to use to address them. It will be a great help to me if there is a term for them so I can make better questions in the future.

Comment: OP (Original Poster) in the context of referring to the asker in the comments or in a linked Post (that is a question). OP can also refer to the answerer when used in context of an answer. "Asker" or "Question Asker" are both appropriate.

Comment: and I'm sure this is a duplicate, though I'll be damned if I can find it.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker please post your first comment as answer.

Comment: @djechlin I think it's bad form to answer a duplicate just to get reputation. It's much better to redirect them to the question that actually has an answer that should get upvotes.  I commented and gave the answer in a comment because I didn't have the link handy to mark this as a duplicate of, and I didn't want to dismiss the user without an answer.